# How to change a page in Microsoft Visio from Foreground to Background?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

How do you move a page, say *Cover* here from '*Foreground Pages*' to '*Background Pages*'?

[image]

I have tried drag 'n drop but not working. Currently my only solution is to create a blank *Background Page*, copy over all the contents then delete and rename - yikes!

Can I just move the original? Using Visio Standard 2016

Comment: The only solution I found was to create a new page of the proper size and copy-paste over the contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the appropriate page tab at the bottom and select **Page Setup**. Select the **Page Properties** tab and change **Type** from Foreground to Background.

Comment: Clean, thank you @Paul Herber!! I wasn't able to find that, thank you :)